# Creating bootstrap columns in angular ng-repeat making issue in width and alignment

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a directive which will create bootstrap columns dynamically . The problem is directive columns width is not equal to the statically creating bootstrap columns.
E.g

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
<div class="row">
  <div  style="background:green" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
  </div>
   <div  style="background:green" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
  </div>
   <div  style="background:green" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

mydirectiveview.html

```
div class="row">
  <div  style="background:red" ng-repeat="tile in Tiles" ng-init="colsspan=12/configInfo.Tiles.length" class="col-sm-{{colsspan}} col-xs-12 col-md-{{colsspan}}>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is width of the directives div is not equal when compare to the div created in static so that the div as not aligned properly

[image]

Can anyone help me in this ??
I want both the directive div and div created in html file should be in same size and aligned properly.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I can't see your directive code, nut mayby

there is something wrong

```
> ng-repeat="tile in Tiles"
> 
> ng-init="colsspan=12/configInfo.Tiles.length"
```

once you've got Titles and after that is configIngo.Titles

please see here for working solution

http://plnkr.co/edit/QoPL5xydTXoX17tV1XZd?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Row class does not behave like table. It will adjust its height and width automatically. i will recommend you to use Table for a smooth layout.

```
<table class="table table-bordered ">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>h1</th>
                        <th>h2</th>
                        <th>h3</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="grid in gridData">
                        <td>{{grid.h1}}</td>
                        <td>{{grid.h2}}</td>
                        <td>{{grid.h3}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```